# Rewrite rule is giving me a 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got the following code in my .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php/?product=$1 [NC, L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```

I'm only getting this 500 error when I have this line in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php/?product=$1 [NC, L]
```

As soon as I remove this line my website works fine again.
Does anyone know what could be wrong with my .htaccess?

Thank you.

Comment: It's `[NC,L]` without space

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first / from the rule.

Comment: Ah, hm. How is this organised? Because you're trying to show something in a subfolder or something? Index.php/ <- that / right there... Should that be there?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+)$ index.php?product=$1 [NC,L]
```